# How do I delete podcasts in iTunes without deleting them from my iPod?

Tags: itunes, ipod

I'm running into a sync behavior that I need to find a way around.  Here's how it worked before (in iTunes 10):

- Using iTunes, I would download a podcast from the internet onto my computer.
- In iTunes, I would transfer the podcast to my iPod.
- In iTunes, I would delete the podcast from my computer.
- Then I would unplug my iPod and listen to the podcast on my iPod.
- If I replugged my iPod into my computer, the podcast would remain on my iPod.

Here's the problem I'm having now (in iTunes 11):

- I download the podcast to my computer,
- transfer the podcast to my iPod,
- delete the podcast from my computer,
- and it also *deletes the podcast from my iPod.*

How do I stop it from deleting things from my iPod when I delete things from iTunes on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you disable auto sync in device settings, and automatic sync manager.

For that however you need to sync the new ones by selecting and dragging to ip*d to sync. That way the ones that got deleted won't be deleted from the device but only from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be a cloud syncing feature - all devices kept in sync everywhere.

Curious why do you want to delete it from your computer before you're ready to delete it from your ipod. I wait until I've listened to the podcast, then resync to the computer, podcast becomes marked as "listened" then I know I can delete.